# How to get "The Giant" zombies map

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3, cod-black-ops-3-zombies

Pretty self-explanatory, I would like to know how can I get the zombies map The Giant on Call of Duty Black ops 3 on Pc as well as if it's released yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that if you buy the Season pass ([available on steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/366843/)), it comes with "The Giant" zombie map. From the link:

> ```
>  About This Content
>  The Call of Duty®: Black Ops III Season Pass delivers 4 epic DLC map packs
>  in 2016 with all-new multiplayer content, including re-imagined 
>  fan-favorite maps from Call of Duty®: World at War and the Call of Duty®: 
>  Black Ops series, plus thrilling Treyarch Zombies content, all for one 
>  great price.*
>
>  Fans that order the Season Pass will be among the first to experience
>  the return of Zombies with “The Giant” Map in all of its undead glory
>  on Day One. Set in a World War II-era research facility featuring the
>  weapon-upgrading Pack-a-Punch Machine, re-live the chaos of Treyarch's
>  classic "Der Riese" Zombies map, picking up the Zombies story with
>  Dempsey, Nikolai, Richtofen, and Takeo where Origins left off.
> ```

Purchasing the Deluxe edition also gives it to you (since it comes with the season pass).

Comment: If I purchase Season Pass today, will I be able to play or I'll have to wait until the map is available to play?

Comment: @zETO I bought the Deluxe edition and it is available to play now (in fact, I just played it earlier today), I can only assume it will be the same for the season pass.